# Android: HTTP/JSON communication within application or separate thread?

Tags: android, json, http, service, multithreading

I've an application which receives and sends data (`JSON`) from/to a `HTTP server` via `HTTP POST requests`.

There is not really any payload except of a few strings, so I'm wondering if it would make sense to build this whole `HTTP` communication as an [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or just to create a separate thread within my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread should be fine unless you need to download data when your application won't be on screen.

Comment: Agreed. Though, if your app is downloading this data for other purposes than displaying it onscreen in some format (if it's truly a background maintenance task) then it might be more correct to make it a service.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I will build it as a separate thread for now.